# TFS Combine Variables with String

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We are conducting a database release in TFS SQL 2015. The plan is to concatenate and variables with strings. Error Message below,

For our deployment release, we have sqlpackage :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe
```

**Method 1 :**

```
/Action:Publish /SourceFile:"$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"\Datawarehouse.dacpac
/Profile:"$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"\Dev.Publish.xml
```

**Method 2 (switching quotes to end):**

```
/Action:Publish /SourceFile:"$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Datawarehouse.dacpac"
/Profile:"$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Dev.Publish.xml"
```

For some reason, TFS is not populating the variable in the logs. How do we conduct this? We want to concatenate a variable with a fixed string.

**Error Message:**

```
2018-12-13T18:43:49.0945356Z *** Error parsing connection string: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\testabcd....\$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Dev.Publish.xml'..
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may create simple cmd file like this:

```
echo off
echo 1: %1
echo 2: %2
echo 3: %3
```

Then copy it to work folder and add build step:
[image]

Result on my environment for the Method 1:

[image]

Method 2:

[image]